# IF statement not working with list difference

Tags: python, django, list

Trying to get the result of the difference between two list, using below code, but doesn't seemed to work.

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']


list3 = list(set(list1) - set(list2))

if not list3: #if not empty, print list3
  print(list3)
else: # if empty print none
  print("None")
```

Comment: `list3` *is* empty. Since you removed all the elements in `list2` from the elements in `list1`. Note that `(-)` is not a commutative "set difference" operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code example, `list3` is indeed empty, since all elements in `list1` are in `list2` as well.

If you are looking for a list that contains the elements in `list1` that are not in `list2` and the elements that are in `list2` and not in `list1`, you should use the *symmetrical set difference* here, this can be performed with the **`^` operator**, like:

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

list3 = list(set(list1) ^ set(list2))
```

if you are, on the other hand looking for elements in `list2` that are not in `list1`, you should swap the operands:

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

list3 = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

If you use `-` you obtain the [*set difference* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) (or *complement*) as in:

A ∖ B = { a∈ A | a∉ B }

whereas the [*symmetrical set difference* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (or the disjunctive union) is:

A ⊕ B = (A ∖ B) ∪ (B ∖ A)

> **Note**: note that the truthiness of a non-empty list is `True` and that of an empty list is `False`. You thus should probably rewrite your printing logic to:
>
> ```
> if list3:  # not empty
>   print(list3)
> else: # is empty
>   print("None")
> ```

Comment: I am actually looking for set difference, 
the ( - ) operator gives me the correct result in list3, as 'four' is not in list1 whereas when checking the condition in "IF" fails i.e., if the list is empty, else should be executed, whereas it is not

Comment: @Pradeep: then you should switch the operands.

Comment: @PradeeP; You made a logical error with the `if` by the way. A list is truthful if it is *not* empty. So you want to negate the condition in the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it using `in`

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

list3 = []
for value in list2:
    if value not in list1:
        list3.append(value)

print(list3)

# outputs ['four']
```